# What resources are tied up by tailing a file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, tail

I'm writing some basic software to run on a simple NAS running debian (sort of) to keep track of some log files in real time.

My fear is that running 'tail' on a file indefinitely might keep the HDD spinning forever as well?  Today, the HDD gets to power down for hours at a time and I don't want to add to that activity if at all possible.

Does anyone know how HDD resource-intensive it is to tail a file that is not actively being written to?

Comment: If tail is doing anything remotely intelligent in follow mode, it should be keeping track of two things: the file's size and it's last seek position.  It should only read if the two are different.

Comment: GNU tail will use inotify if possible, so it will consume zero CPU and zero disk access. If inotify is not available, it will stat the file every few seconds.

Comment: If you want to know exactly how it works you can always hava a look at the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c)

Comment: What do you mean by _running 'tail' on a file indefinitely_ - starting `tail -f` once, or starting `tail` without `-f` repeatedly?